# RadPanelBar / RadDataGrid relative Width binding to item child?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, telerik, styles

So what I'm trying to accomplish you can see in the image example provided. I must not be using the correct width binding? Basically I have a RadPanelBar with a RadDataGrid embedded in a RadPanelBarItem that keeps showing out of the viewable area when loaded. I need it to respect the width of the cell and adjust for a GridSplitter. So it should just stretch the available width of its Parent and continue to to stretch with a GridSplitter Movement. Any ideas? What would the proper MaxWidth binding format?

```
<telerik:RadPanelBarItem x:Name="QuickFind" Header="Quick Find" IsExpanded="True">
       <StackPanel x:Name="Container" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox x:Name="QuickSearch" 
              cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp]=[Action QuickSearchKeyUp($eventArgs, $this.Text)]" />
            <telerik:RadGridView ShowGroupPanel="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoExpandGroups="True" ShowColumnHeaders="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" Width="{Binding ElementName=Container,Path=ActualWidth}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" CanUserResizeColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action QuickSearchItemSelect($this.SelectedItem)]" x:Name="ResultsGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding QuickFindService.Results}" >
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
              <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Results" UniqueName="Results" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" />                        
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>>
        </telerik:RadGridView>
      </StackPanel>
```

[image: RadDataGrid width binding]

Comment: It might help if you post the code for the grid/panelbar that you're talking about.

Comment: Good point, was late and tired when I posted. The current method will make the maxwidth correct at runtime, but then doesn't allow it to adjust Width with the gridslitter, thanks for any insight!

Comment: I just don't understand why you would have to manually adjust the width anyway... if you use the correct container then the datagrid should just fill the parent container and there would be no need to bind any width properties. I've never had to bind width properties.

Comment: Oh, now I see your code... try taking out the stackpanel called container and replace it with a Grid. Whenever you need something to stretch (horizontally or vertically) and fill something (like its parent container) you should never use a stackpanel, always a grid. I think you'll see a difference if you just lay the stuff out with a Grid. I think this way will work just fine and you won't have to bind the parent's width, just set the datagrid to stretch horizontally and vertically.

Comment: For some reason a stackpanel doesn't respect the boundries of its parent container the same way that a grid does...

Comment: Really? Well damn I'll have to try that real quick and see if I can't just get around that way. I wonder why it wouldnt respect the boundary of its parent? That is weird, will let you know my results. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you there, all I know is that the guy who sits in the cubicle next to mine always tries to use stack panels for everything and complains every time they don't stretch to fill or shrink to fit... I always just say: use a grid!

Comment: Tried it with grid, it still pushes the boundary of the RadPanelBarItem out past just stretch. For now though its not as much of a concern since I've got to skip past it. I'll save this mystery for another day, thanks Barry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so since with using the GridSplitter and the RadDataGrid I couldn't find anything that would fire off a property change to width value when the grid splitter is used. So ditched the RadDataGrid for an Item Control and solved it with the standard Stretch method.

In other words binding to the ActualWidth of something that wont trigger a PropertyChanged event caused by something like a GridSplitter wont give you a dynamic value you bind a width property to. Solved...for now :)